# How to run specifics sniffs with PHP Code Sniffer

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I got PHP Code Sniffer 2.6.0. I'm using phpcs and it's working fine.
I have a huge project in PHP 5.2.17, more than 2000 classes, and it will migrate to 5.6.20. 
I want to focus on refactoring classes with deprecated PHP functions first. I'm tried to run only Generic.PHP.DeprecatedFunctions and Squiz.PHP.ForbiddenFunctions sniffs without luck. Used the command:

> phpcs --standard=Squiz --sniffs=Squiz.PHP.ForbiddenFunctions /path/to/class

I got the error:

> ERROR: option "--sniffis=Squiz.PHP.ForbiddenFunctions" not known.

What I'm missing?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. phpcs just found the class if the current path is phpcs root.